# component.html 404 Not Found when the component is in JavaScript and not TypeScript [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

Given a template, eg. `src/app/x.component.html`:

```
<em>Hello</em>
```

and a component `src/app/x.component.ts`:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
@Component({
  selector: 'x-y',
  templateUrl: './x.component.html'
})
export class XComponent {}
```

the component works: it displays *Hello*.

Now, writing the same in pure JS, ie. `src/app/x.component.js`:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
export class XComponent {}
XComponent.annotations = [
  new Component({
    selector: 'x-y',
    templateUrl: './x.component.html'
  })
]
```

will result in the errors
`GET /x.component.html 404 (Not Found)`
`Failed to load x.component.html`.
So `@angular/cli` seems to look for the template in `/`, for some reason.

***However***, using an inline template instead of the external one, like:

```js
  ...
  new Component({
    selector: 'x-y',
    template: `<em>Hello</em>`
  })
  ...
```

works!

**Question**: What am I doing wrong? How to get `templateUrl` to work for plain JavaScript components too?

*I'm using Angular 7.2.13 and Angular CLI 7.3.8*

Comment: I copied your code into a stackblitz project and it works.  But I might not fully understand what you are doing...  Just make sure all the paths are correct in each file, as well as in the app.module.ts file...  Here is the link:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcatca

Comment: @MarkB Indeed, on StackBlitz it seems to work. I have renamed your `x.component.ts` to `.js` to be like my setup, but it still works. But StackBlitz must do something special, for example annotations work in `.js` files, whereas in a default `ng new` project they don't. I'm just trying to use Angular with JavaScript. The paths are correct, it's just that `@angular/cli` seems to look in the root for a template when the component is in JS. Good to know StackBlitz have somehow worked around this, or maybe the old version of `@angular/cli` they use didn't have this issue?